# Can I use `purple-facebook` with empathy?

Tags: empathy, facebook, libpurple

Facebook dropped the XMPP support. Since `pidgin` solution is to merge with `purple-facebook`... and `empathy` uses `libpurple`... can I somehow use `empathy` with `purple-facebook`?

I installed the package but there's no new protocol showing in `empathy`. With `pidgin` it works fine, this question doesn't regard `pidgin`.

Comment: Yes you can. Through telepathy-haze. After installing just run `empathy accounts` in terminal. And then set up facebook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To install the purple-facebook plugin, choose one of the following:

- You can try building it from source yourself: https://github.com/dequis/purple-facebook/wiki/Building-on-*NIX
- Add a repository, see https://jgeboski.github.io/#package-repositories
- Or download a deb-package from the repository and install it manually: http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/jgeboski/

To make 'facebook manager' show up when adding a new account:

1. Download `haze-accounts-extensions-facebookmessenger-0.4-1.noarch.rpm` (or any later version) on 
   https://openrepos.net/content/nodevel/facebook-messenger-account
2. Extract it into your file-system root, i.e. `/`.

This should work for empathy and any other client that uses telepathy-haze.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't use empathy any more - did you actually try it? Does it work? If so, I'll mark this as a solution. Otherwise I'd prefer to wait for someone to confirm it works.

Comment: I tried it with kde-telepathy, for which it works. I didn't try with empathy, though empathy uses the telepathy backend, so it should work.

Comment: Doesn't work for me on Empathy/Unity with purple-facebook installed from the PPA of jgebovski.

Comment: Did you install `haze-accounts-extensions-facebookmessenger`?